# Kinect Color Frame Form

Tags: kinect, openkinect

I am curious about the format of the Color Frame in Kinect. Is it RGB or BRG + alpha. I think the information coming is in BRG format but could some clarify this for me

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can select it by declaring a color format. Here's the reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.colorimageformat.aspx)

Comment: This is correct for the official SDK.  Given the tags on the question, I believe they are looking for OpenKinect though.